# What is the meaning of Y~0|X1+X2... syntax

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I have encountered logistic regression code with the format

```
mlogit(Y ~ 0| X1 + X2 +...Xn)
```

What is the difference between this and syntax of the form

```
mlogit(Y ~ X1 + X2 +... Xn)
```

I am familiar with the use of syntax of the form

```
glm(Y ~ X1 + X2 + ... Xn, family = 'binomial')
```

as standard R syntax for multiple logistic regression of outcome Y against predictors. I am not familiar with the syntax of Y ~ 0| X1 + ... Xn and would appreciate a clarification of what the difference is.

Comment: I'm guessing you are using the `mlogit` package for the `mlogit` function. The `?mlogit` help page points you to the `?mFormula` for more information about what formulas mean to that function. Formulas can be interpreted different ways by different functions/packages. You need to read the documentation for whatever function you are using in order to know what the syntax means.

Comment: Actually, I'm working with another individual's code, and have no experience with mlogit. I have always used glm to perform logistic regression. However, his code (with mlogit) has both the Y ~ X1+..Xn and Y~ 0| X1 + ...Xn syntax, so I'm trying to understand the difference (if any)

Comment: See `?mlogit` as MrFlick said.

Comment: `?mFormula` will bring you to [mFormula help page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mlogit/versions/1.0-1/topics/mFormula), which explains `0|` and `1|` syntax in formulas. I think it's Mixed Effects model.